# utilizando DISTINCT como puedo consultar varios registros de una tabla?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT IdOcupacion, Codigo, Descripcion
FROM Ocupaciones
```

Sobre la cual en el campo de `Descripcion` me aparecen varios registros dobles y me gustaría saber cómo que al consultar solo me aparezca uno de los registros pero que me traiga los campos del `idOcupacion` y el `Codigo` de la ocupación. gracias

Comment: Falta que expliques cuál es el que debería retornar (si es que hay más de uno). Con qué lógica quieres elegir uno de los registros por el sobre el resto?

Comment: sobre la descripcion tengo ejemplo mil campos repetidos igual con el campo codigo, entre codigo y descipcion los campos se encuentran repetidos en aproximadamente mil registros lo que necesito es obtener solo uno de los dos registros que estan repetidos y poder consultarlos con su correspondiente id

Comment: Es que a eso me refiero, al haber muchos repetidos no hay un único "correspondiente id". Cuál id es el que debería ser elegido?

Comment: Si se repite la descripción el id sera distinto entonces no se cual seria el problema, si el caso es buscar solo 1 vez la descripcion con el DISTINC funciona

Comment: @SantiagoRoldan El problema es que el op quiere elegir una única descripción, pero también elegir el id "correspondiente"

Comment: El caso seria si tiene un registro id: 1, descripción y un id: 2, descripción, tiene diferente id y la misma descripción como hacer para saber que id quiere que se muestre, supongo yo

Comment: @SantiagoRoldan claro, eso es exactamente lo que le he preguntado ya en un par de comentarios

Comment: |3426 2636 ABAD|
|14123 2636 ABAD|
|14124 2636 ABADESA|
|3427 2636 ABADESA|
|6736 5249 ABARROTERO|
|17433 5249 ABARROTERO|

tengo estos regisatros, quiero consultar de tal forma de que me los traiga haci

|3426 2636 ABAD|
|14124 2636 ABADESA|
|6736 5249 ABARROTERO|

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Prueba esto, espero que te sirva

```
SELECT IdOcupacion, Codigo, Descripcion
FROM Ocupaciones where IdOcupacion = /*Al codigo de ocupacion que deseas ver*/
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el objetivo de usar ese query? Con un poco más de explicación talvés podamos entender mejor lo que deseas transmitir y desde mi punto de vista tu respuesta no tiene relación con el problema que presenta el OP

Comment: Bien, lo que quiero transmitir es lo siguiente, si el tiene otra tabla aparte de ocupación, las unirá y le traerá el campo código, y la descripción, porque el esta uniendo los datos para que sean un registro como lo que el espera

Comment: El que hagas la unión entre tablas no asegura que tengas resultados únicos, además de que el OP solo dice que tiene una sola tabla, no habría necesidad de usar una segunda

Comment: Tienes la razón pensaba que tenia dos tablas porque lo que el esta haciendo ahora que observe la pregunta bien es poner idOcupacion y código es el mismo idOcupacion,  no hay necesidad

Answer (score 1):

Aún no explicas cómo elegir un registro sobre el otro, pero bueno, puedes modificar la siguiente consulta para obtenerlo:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT IdOcupacion, 
          Codigo, 
          Descripcion,
          RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Codigo, Descripcion 
                                 ORDER BY IdOcupacion)
   FROM Ocupaciones
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1;
```